# Select Date from a Datetime value

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to select Date part from a DateTime value using Linq to Sql or sql lambda.
Here is my scenario.

```
dbContext.PurchaseOrders.Where(r => r.ReqDate == DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Here ReqDate is a DateTime field. I want to select all the purchase orders for today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It shouild be as simple as just using the `Date` property in `DateTime`:

**UPDATE:** From the 3rd error in the comments I see that `ReqDate` is A `Nullable<DateTime>`. Try using the `Value` property to access the underlying `DateTime` object:

```
dbContext.PurchaseOrders.Where(r => r.ReqDate.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
    .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you could try the not-so-pretty option:

```
dbContext.PurchaseOrders.Where(r => r.ReqDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    .ToList();
```

Just convert your `DateTime` objects to a string formatted to contain the date only.

Comment: No its not working. Gives an error like this - Delegate 'System.Func<Models.PurchaseOrders,int,bool>'

Comment: @Mukesh - Could you be more specific? What's the exact error message? I've added an alternative in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it gives 3 error messages 1. Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: 2. Delegate 'System.Func<Models.PurchaseOrder,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: 3. 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your 3rd error. The `Nullable<DateTime>` might be "wrecking havoc" here. =)

Comment: @Mukesh - Which one, the `.ToString()` version, the `ReqDate.Value` version or neither?

Comment: And you're getting the exact same errors? Error 3 should be gone by now at least...

Comment: Ya!!! I got it working. It was my mistake that, my db field was null. That was the proble. Its okay now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

I have an answer that will return a list. Long way I know but I could not find a solution anywhere.

I hope this save someone else the frustration. I have been searching and searching to find an answer to this issue.

It does a group by on datetime to return a list of dates with no time. In my case it was to load a combo box of dates to choose from.

```
      var mADates = from ta in db.AM_Assignments
                      orderby ta.Assignment_DTM 
                      group ta by ta.Assignment_DTM.Date; 

        List<DateTime> dtx = new List<DateTime>();

        foreach (var dt in mADates)
        {
            dtx.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Key.ToShortDateString()));
        }
        return dtx;
```

Comment: Needed that version myself - see below for a slight update to it

Answer (score 1):

Use the Subtract method.

```
dbContext.PurchaseOrders.Where(r => DateTime.Now.Subtract(r.ReqDate).Days == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Gives this error - Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Are you sure that your dates are a DateTime and not some other type?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
dbContext.PurchaseOrders.Where(r => r.ReqDate.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

.Date creates a 00:00:00 time so time is not compared

```
dbContext.PurchaseOrders.Where(r => r.ReqDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some LINQ2SQL functions that imitate native SQL ones. One of them - truncation of time from `DateTime?` or `DateTimeOffset?`.

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
dbContext.PurchaseOrders.Where(r => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.ReqDate).Value == today).ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and such an obscure fact that I wonder why this answer doesn't have more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

More compact version of @Angus 's code

```
var mADates = from ta in db.AM_Assignments
                      orderby ta.Assignment_DTM 
                      group ta by ta.Assignment_DTM.Date;

return mADates.Select(dt => Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Key.ToShortDateString())).ToList();
```